# Recurring subscription payment redirecting user to summary page after login in Sandbox

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, paypal-sandbox

We are facing an issue in recurring subscription payment in Sandbox Paypal. After login it is redirecting user to “Account summary” page instead of “return URL”.
The normal Payment works fine but the issue is in subscription only.
We have also checked that return url is also correct and without underscore.

Please let us know if I am missing something or need to configure for any changes.

Please find below code

[1] Paypal generated

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="7MXXRWH7Z5PSQ">
<input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_GB/i/btn/btn_subscribe_SM.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

[2] Custom

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions" />
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="vishal@eminentinfoweb.com" />
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2" />

    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Baseball Hat Monthly" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="123" />
    <input type="hidden" name="a3" value="5.00" />
    <input type="hidden" name="p3" value="3" />
    <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M" />
    <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1" />

    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="(return url)" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return"  value="(cancel url)" />
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="(notify url)" />
    <input type="hidden" value="Colorado Springs" name="city" id="city">
    <input type="hidden" value="US" name="country" id="country">
    <input type="hidden" value="vishal@eminentinfoweb.com" name="email" id="email">
    <input type="hidden" value="Tahir" name="first_name" id="first_name">
    <input type="hidden" value="Yasin" name="last_name" id="last_name">
    <input type="hidden" value="80903" name="zip" id="zip">
    <input type="hidden" value="CO" name="state" id="state">
    <input type="hidden" value="219 W. Colorado Avenue Suite 200" name="address1" id="address1">
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="address2" id="address2">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="address_override" id="address_override">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Subscribe" />
</form>
```

Comment: Hey Mittul, thanks for the response, no I am trying live url not a localhost

Comment: yes already checked that and generated a ticket in Paypal too.

Comment: yes that comes only under live account where i have already enabled the same and set the return url too.

Comment: I have used the plugin and it works in plugin properly, but I want the value to be set dynamically which option is not there in plugin.

Comment: no man just checked, now the same issue in plugin too.

Comment: actually first i tried with plugin only, then this requirement of dynamic subscription comes, so i have implemented this code which seems not to be working.

Comment: ok but when you tried subscription feature with plugin itself, was it working fine ? was it redirecting ?

Comment: yes it was working before